# How to prove the following result involving $ TT^*$?

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces

If $T$ is a bounded linear operator between Hilbert spaces. Then how to prove that $$\left(\sum_{j=1}^{k} a_j(T^*T)^{j-1}\right)TT^*y = 0$$ if and only if $TT^*y$ is sum of at most $k-1$ eigen vectors of $TT^*$. Here $a_i$ are real numbers and $T^*$ is adjoint of $T$.

Comment: What if $TT^*y=0$?

Comment: Suppose $T: H_1 \rightarrow H_2$ where $H_1 \neq H_2$, then I don't understand your statement. So is $H_1 = H_2?$.

Comment: @ Martin Argerami, it is non zero.